# Why are some Azure-specific assemblies not present on Azure instances?

Tags: .net, deployment, azure, assemblies, gac

An Azure role will likely need a set of Azure-specific .NET assemblies like `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime` and `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient`. Turns out the latter is [not in the GAC on Azure instances](http://blog.arunstephens.com/2011/01/16/microsoft-windowsazure-storageclient-is-not-actually-on-azure/) and so I have to set "Copy Local" to "True" in the Visual Studio project so that it gets into the service package and deployed to Azure. If I don't do that the assembly is not there and the missing dependency will prevent my role from starting.

This doesn't make any sense to me. Either it's just a bug or I don't get the big picture.

Is there a good reason why the key assemblies would not be present in Azure instances GAC and I have to carry them with my service package?

Comment: I always use this nice tool before deployment [List Of Assemblies Running On Windows Azure](http://gacviewer.cloudapp.net/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

These key Azure assemblies aren't a part of the .NET Framework - that's why they are not in the GAC. Maybe in the future they will be added to the .NET Framework.

Azure is not dedicated to running only .NET code. [People use it for other platforms](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/overview/) such as Java, PHP, node.js, python, etc. It wouldn't make sense to add assemblies that are specific to .NET Azure implementations in the VM Role Instances.

Yes - this was also an annoyance when I first started on Azure, but the same is true if you would have published this on-premise to a machine without the Azure SDK.

Comment: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll (the most important or 'key' assembly) is in the GAC.  Only the storage client is not in the GAC.

Comment: @dunnry: Yeap, and this inconsistency is even more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there a good reason why the key assemblies would not be present in Azure instances GAC and I have to carry them with my service package?

I would like to point out that not every project needs to work with storage, so it makes sense the storage assembly is not pre-installed. One less assembly to load, a tiny performance improvement you get. But every project need to be integrated with Windows Azure runtime. So runtime assemblies are pre-installed. From my experience, by default when we create a Windows Azure web/worker role, the storage assembly reference automatically has copy local set to true. Thus, we don’t need to do extra tasks to make it work.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: It's true that we don't need to do anything to make it work, but the assembly inflates the service package. Not that it is a very serious problem, I just want to point out that there are negative consequences to no having it in the GAC.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. You can also submit a feature request on http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting.